# Minimal Account Permissions

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I want to create a user account on my Ubuntu server, that just has permission to be accessed by ssh, read the attributes of a few files, and nothing else.

I've created a new non-sudo account, but my experience with Ubuntu is limited. What's the best way of creating a locked down account like this?

Comment: If you restrict the access only to `public key authentication`, you may further restrict the possibilites of the account by editing `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (see `man sshd` for further information). If this is an option, I could try to assist in realization.

Answer (score 2):

Account Permissions should be custom to each machine and scenario. I recommend reading into these man pages to create your own level of account permissions. To do so run each commands manual page proceed the command with `man` as in this style:

```
man users
```

or

```
man groupadd
```

I recommend groups which uses these commands:
`groups` `groupadd` `groupdel` `groupmod`

I also recommend checking into user commands:
`users` `useradd` `userdel` and `usermod`

There is also the change commands:
`chmod` `chown` `chgrp`

Utilize their man pages to create custom account permissions. Good Luck!